# Graphite server shows blank kafka metrics while using collectd JMX and java plugin

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, graphite, collectd

I am using collectd JMX and java plugin to gather kafka metrics and write to graphite server. When I run the command to see kafka metrics from the node it shows the data but when I use collectd plugin blank metrics are exported. Any idea if I am missing some configuration. Below is the sample code snipped

Comment: <Plugin java>
   JVMARG "-Djava.class.path=/usr/share/collectd/java/collectd-api.jar:/usr/share/collectd/java/generic-jmx.jar"
   LoadPlugin "org.collectd.java.GenericJMX"
   <Plugin "GenericJMX">
       <MBean "kafka-all-messages">
           ObjectName "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec"
           <Value>
               Type "counter"
               Table false
               Attribute "Count"
           </Value>
       </MBean>
<Connection>
  ServiceURL"service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:2999/jmxrmi"
  Host "localhost"
</Connection>

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<Plugin java> 
JVMARG "-Djava.class.path=/usr/share/collectd/java/collectd-api.jar‌​:/usr/share/collectd‌​/java/generic-jmx.ja‌​r" 
LoadPlugin "org.collectd.java.GenericJMX" 
    <Plugin "GenericJMX"> 
        <MBean "kafka-all-messages"> 
            ObjectName "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec" 
            <Value> 
                Type "counter" 
                Table false 
                Attribute "Count" 
            </Value> 
        </MBean> 
        <Connection> 
            ServiceURL"service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:2999/jmxr‌​mi" 
            Host "localhost" 
            Collect "kafka-all-messages"
        </Connection>
    </Plugin>
</Plugin>
```